# Lightning getReference() on a helper function rather than component function

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

Using `component.getReference("c.thisComponentFunction")` to grab a reference for dynamically created components is a known feature. I'm not finding any documentation (or possibility) to do the same for a helper function for the same component.

**Controller:**

```
({
  doSomething : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.getReference("c.doSomethingElse"); //regular usage
    //component.getReference("helper.somethingElseInHelper"); //doesn't work
  },
  doSomethingElse : function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.somethingElseInHelper(component);
  },
})
```

**Helper:**

```
({
  somethingElseInHelper : function(component) {
    alert("you're in the helper!");
  },
})
```

Is there a way to directly access `"helper.somethingElseInHelper"` with `component.getReference()`?

Comment: Looks like the answer is "No, unless you're extending a component" which kind of defeats the purpose. It's easier to just add a dispatcher function on the component to its helper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly access a helper of another component unless you are extending it. You will need to create a controller method to give access to a helper method.

Comment: Edited for clarity and what I want to achieve. I'm in the same component, can you clarify what you mean by extending it?

Comment: Check this one out for extending components , https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/03/salesforce-lightning-components-by-example-component-extension.html

Comment: That's a great feature. I'm not seeing it apply directly to my use case unless I basically have a component with only helpers - and extend THAT for my `component.getReference("c.someHelperFunction")`. I guess that's the workaround.